# Input h, j, k, l in gtk applications with vi style keybindings

Tags: vim, gtk, keyboard-shortcuts

Here is a receipe from vim tips:

```
# /usr/share/themes/Vi/gtk-2.0-key/gtkrc
# A key-binding set for vi-like key-bindings

binding "gtk-vi-text-view"
{
  bind "<ctrl>d" { "move-cursor" (display-lines, 5, 0) }
  bind "<ctrl>f" { "move-cursor" (display-lines, 5, 0) }
  bind "<ctrl>u" { "move-cursor" (display-lines, -5, 0) }
  bind "<ctrl>b" { "move-cursor" (display-lines, -5, 0) }
  bind "<ctrl>e" { "move-cursor" (display-lines, -1, 0) }
  bind "<ctrl>y" { "move-cursor" (display-lines, 1, 0) }
  bind "j" { "move-cursor" (display-lines, 1, 0) }
  bind "k" { "move-cursor" (display-lines, -1, 0) }
  bind "l" { "move-cursor" (logical-positions, 1, 0) }
  bind "h" { "move-cursor" (logical-positions, -1, 0) }
}

binding "gtk-vi-tree-view"
{
  bind "j" { "move-cursor" (display-lines, 1) }
  bind "k" { "move-cursor" (display-lines, -1) }
  bind "l" { "move-cursor" (logical-positions, 1) }
  bind "h" { "move-cursor" (logical-positions, -1) }
}

class "GtkTextView" binding "gtk-vi-text-view"
class "GtkTreeView" binding "gtk-vi-tree-view"

# The last part is to note your local gtk configuration file. Check in your home directory file named '.gtkrc-2.0'. and "touch" it. The only thing left to be done is appending:

gtk-key-theme="Vi"
```

This is all fine, but the problem is, under this configuration it's no longer possible to input the letters
h, j, k and l. How can this be solved?

Comment: Hi qed, does this still work for you? I wanted to do it so badly but I'm afraid it has been phased out. I tried `gtk-key-theme-name` as suggested at https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Vi_key_bindings_in_gtk but it was none the better... (Yes I tested in GTK2 application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have missed the elephant in the room: Vi(m) is a *modal* editor while the `GtkTextView` widget is rather obviously not.

Non-modal editors or textfield widgets like the one you are playing with have their own way of handling the alpha-numerical keys of your keyboard: modifier keys.

Either

- you hit a key to enter some kind of mode where you can hit `hjkl` without inserting them in your text

or

- you press `hjkl` *plus* a modifier key.

Those are basically your only alternatives.

Using `hjkl` for cursor movement *only* makes sense when the user is in a mode that prevents him/her to insert what he/she types. It may "work" in `GtkTreeView` or in other contexts where the user is not expected to type text, though.

So… I'm not sure you really gave much thought to your problem.